# Can I use unique and nullable attributes in CharField with tortoise?

Tags: database, orm, field, tortoisesvn, database-migration

Can I do the following to make a charfield unique and not null using tortoise orm?

```
class User(Model):
    id = fields.IntField(pk = True)
    username = fields.CharField(max_length = 128, unique = True, nullable = False)
```

Or what would be the appropriate field?
Is there a field for email type data? or which one should be used
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The docs specify max_input and **kwargs as input parameters for CharField.

https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#tortoise.fields.data.CharField

You can find the **kwargs for CharField in its parent class, the base Field.

https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html#tortoise.fields.base.Field

There you find parameters like:

- **null (bool)** – Is this field nullable?
- **unique (bool)** – Is this field unique?
- **validators (Optional[List[Union[Validator, Callable]]])** – Validators for this field.

See the docs for more info on how to use validators: https://tortoise-orm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/validators.html